# Add superscript in Sublime Text

Tags: text

I inherited a line of code with the following type of superscript:

```
nm³
```

I cannot seem to change - or replicate - the <sup>3</sup> superscript. This particular <sup>3</sup> superscript seems distinct from that which I can create in Text Edit.app, or Microsoft Word (i.e., <sup>3</sup>), because when I paste the superscript I create in one of those into Sublime Text, the superscript is not retained (i.e., it looks just like this: `nm3`).

In particular, I'd like to change it to <sup>2</sup>. Is there a way to do this with Sublime Text, another text editor, or through a different approach? Why is this superscript different?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possibility is that the character that you have is the UNICODE “Superscript three” ³ character (code U+0083, in the UTF-8 encoding the couple of bytes C2 B3). In this case you can substitute it with the “Superscript two” ² character (code U+0082, in the UTF-8 encoding the couple of bytes C2 B2).

If this is the case, you can copy and paste any of these characters: ¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹⁰.

Comment: Thanks. How did you generate these hard-coded superscript characters?

Comment: @user1794295 , it depends on the operating system and/or the writing software that you are using. In my case I used a Mac OS X computer that has at the level of the operating system a palette where you can choose any UNICODE character and insert it in any application.

Comment: Thus, Character Map on Windows.